# ODBC connection issue to load data. Copy Activity source not working

Tags: azure, db2, azure-data-factory, ibm-midrange, azure-data-lake

I am using odbc connector to connect to AS400 DB2 system. I am fetching metadata from copy activity and it is throwing the following error.

Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS] - Error message text unavailable. Message can not be translated successfully.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS] - Error message text unavailable. Message can not be translated successfully.,Source=CWBODBC.DLL,'

We have read access to the database. Is this access error for the given user? Or network connectivity issue because some copy activity runs while some fail. We are trying to load the data in data lake and everything is parameterized. Let me know if this is a library for Windows issue/Network issue/access issue.?

Comment: Does this happen for all queries\tables you try to access? Also, you can try the ADF connector for DB2 instead of the ODBC connector - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-db2?tabs=data-factory

Comment: @ChenHirsh no for some tables it runs and some fails and that occurrence is random. Some copy activity fails for some tables but none is passingby.

Comment: Looks like you might be using an old driver. IBM i hasn't been called i5/OS for many years, and System i Access predates Windows 8. though IBM also isn't known for changing names everywhere immediately, the new drivers come from IBM iACS. What version is the OS you are connecting to? Currently IBM i is at v7.5

Answer (score 0):

If it is as you say, a transient issue in copy activity, it is highly likely that it is network related. Some network errors are caused by the underlying driver (in fact it is common in Azure-SSIS scenarios where the driver in the SSISDB is old).

If you could write about how you set up the connector, it might be useful. Try changing the driver, first try with IBM db2 ODBC driver:

Are you using SHIR or Azure IR ? if it is SHIR, then you need further instructions on how to install the driver to the machine.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=dsd-installing-data-server-driver-odbc-cli-software-windows-operating-systems

For Azure IR, unfortunately you cannot choose which driver you want. If you have this problem with Azure IR, then you can consider using the ODBC connector to connect and see if it works (I assume you are on DB2 connector):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory

Comment: No we are using ODBC connector in adf.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And IR ? if its SHIR, try changing the driver.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like transient issue related to network or driver may be. Its
> not looking like amy permission related issue. Are you using Self
> hosted IR here? If yes could you please try to reinstall it or upgrade
> it and see if that helps.